# Unable to locate element for date picker

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation

I am trying to locate an element

[image]

The structure is `<div>June 2023</div>` to locate a particular month year value which is the header of the date picker

I am unable to create a unique identifier from this above line, please help.

Unable to make a CSS selector/XPATH identifier

Comment: Update the question with the text based HTML of the element.

Comment: Please show us the HTML element you are trying to click. Also provide the site URL. Using a picture is poor idea.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a complete [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase) solution that selects a date in the date-picker for that site.

First `pip install seleniumbase`. Then run with `python`:

```py
from seleniumbase import BaseCase
BaseCase.main(__name__, __file__)

class MakeMyTripTest(BaseCase):
    def test_makemytrip(self):
        self.open("https://www.makemytrip.com/flights/")
        self.click('p[data-cy="departureDate"]')
        self.click('div[aria-label="Fri Jun 30 2023"] p')
        self.sleep(5)
```